# I'm having problems getting RenPy Language extension to work

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, renpy

[image]I'm new to both RenPy and VSC so I might be doing something wrong but the RenPy Language extension doesn't work for me for some reason. All of the syntax comes up as error and it seems to me that the problem might be that the .rpy file doesn't get recognized for some reason since .py files that I use with the Python extension work just fine.

If anyone has any suggestion it would be very appreciated.

Comment: Please supplement the error content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being Ren'Py as the Language Mode. Because I have both it and Python installed, VSC picked Python to read .rpy files so nothing was working.

Answer (score 0):

*(My reputation isn't enough to insert a picture. Links in this answer are all screenshots.)*

It seems that your "Ren'Py Language" extension isn't enabled.

My file tree on the left likes this. You can see the Ren'Py icon on the left of .rpy files:
[extension enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAGI0.png)

When I disabled this extension, The icon changes to Python:
[extension disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otaPl.png)

Opening *screens.rpy*, the lint is for python so it's full of errors, which is just like yours:
[lint doomed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpuaQ.png)

So your Ren'Py extension may not be installed properly. Check it out.

The extension I'm using is *LuqueDaniel.languague-renpy*. You can follow this official guide to install extensions: https://code.visualstudio.com/learn/get-started/extensions